# R comment cancellation by ctrl+shift+c brings <!-- #

Tags: r, comments

I produce comment and disables the # by the ctrl+shift+c and somehow the disabling part always brings <!-- #, rather than erasing the symbol for me.

[image]

Comment: Is the file you're using this with have a .html extension?

Comment: I should check. Thanks for the comment.